# Getting Vba in excel to enter information from a userform to the next empty coulmn

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to using vba and I've been trying to come up with a userform that will take information given and enter it into the next empty cell below it here is the code i've been trying to use but it is failing

```
       Dim iRow As Long
       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
       Row = 1
       Range("A2").Value = Me.txtDate.Value
       iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
```

If anyone has a solution i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Looking at `Me.txtDate.Value` this must be in a Form module. Which event are you using to fire the code?

Comment: When you say fire up do you mean initiate? if that is im just using the play button in vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to find after you've already put the value into A2 but this may be able to replace all of the code you supplied.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.txtDate.Value
```

This is the equivalent of starting at the bottom row of column A (A1048576) and tapping `Ctrl+<up arrow>` then moving down one cell.